# How to use google translate api all pages

Tags: google-translate

I'm using google translate api on my web page. I added google translate script to index.php. There are many pages on my web page. İf I pass to another page google translate script doesnt work, just work on my added page. I want to use all pages. Should I add google translate script all pages one by one? İs there any easy way to add all pages?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will  have to add it to all pages.

register your website here https://translate.google.com/manager/website/

Once you add the code on all pages, all pages will translate automatically based on user first selection. User does not have to choose preferred language on each page.

Answer (score 0):

### I'm not sure if I understand your question...

*If you want to dynamically include your google translate api code to all pages than you can do this in multiple ways*

```
1. create one translate.js file with the api code inside. 
then use include("translate.js"); in all pages where you need it.

2. create inline <script>(paste here, translate api code)</script> 
in dynamic header or footer page if you've one already. than use

include("header.php"); use it in all pages where you need it. 
if you place the tracking code in a header file..

include("footer.php"); use it in all pages where you need it. 
if you place the translate code in a footer file..
```